# Upload media files to Amazon S3

Tags: images, media, thumbnails, amazon

I have a site that is running on AppFog.com, and they don't have persistent file storage for things like images uploaded through the wordpress media uploader.

The theme I am making for the site includes the Amazon S3 PHP class for some other functionality - and I have that working. What I would now like to do is hook that into the media uploader so that when images are uploaded to my site they also get uploaded to Amazon S3.

So I guess what I want is to know what filters are used when uploading media so that I can hook into them and also upload the images (and the relevant thumbnails) to S3. I tried looking through the source but haven't had any joy so far.

I should point out that I don't really want to use a plugin to do this - but I am happy to learn from a plugin if anyone has any pointers.

Also - since I am using AppFog I don't have access to the server and so can't install anything beyond PHP apps.

Comment: See if you can work out what you need from [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp2cloud-wordpress-to-cloud/).

Comment: I've looked at that plugin. It uses the Clouse storage system (http://www.oblaksoft.com/documentation/) which seems to need to add some sort of addon to mysql - which is something I can't do unfortunately.

You're right that I may be able to use some of the code as a starting point though so will look into it some more.

Comment: I was mostly looking at the (significant number of) hooks it uses.

Comment: It's true - there's a lot. I'm looking at it at the moment :)

Answer (score 1):

So I worked out what I was looking for. It seems that all images, when edited or uploaded, have something passed through **wp_update_attachment_metadata** and so I can hook into that to get the info I need.